# How to output the results of deflater in GZIP format?

Tags: java, gzip, deflate

I'm using Java.

I want to use the [Deflater class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) to deflate some input, then I want to output it in GZIP format so it could be unzipped with GZIP.  How can I do this?  My understanding is it will output it in a different format.  I'm a noob, so if you could be explicit and maybe give a code example that would be super helpful.

I can't use GZIPOutputStream because I need to use some Deflater class specific features before outputting.

Comment: What Deflater class features do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `GZIPOutputStream` uses `Deflater` under the hood anyway, so you're not trying to do anything all that crazy.

One possibility (from [this page](http://www.redirecttonull.com/?p=134), which is probably worth a read) is to subclass `GZIPOutputStream` so that you can access its `Deflater` object. Something more or less like this (untested):

```
public class MyGZIPOutputStream extends GZIPOutputStream {

  public MyGZIPOutputStream(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    super(out);
  }

  public void setDictionary(byte[] b) {
    def.setDictionary(b);
  }

}
```

Then you can make your setDictionary call before using your `MyGZIPOutputStream` to save the file.

The variable `def` is a protected member of `GZIPOutputStream`, so subclassing is necessary to access it.

Answer (score 0):

First question is why?

GZIPping the output of Deflater means that the recipient must both GUnzip and inflate.

GZIPping the output of Deflater may increase the size. It certainly won't compress it significantly.

If you need GZIP output, forget about the Deflater.

If you need the dictionary, forget about the GZIP output.

Comment: I don't want to GZIP the output, I want to output it in GZIP format so that it can be unzipped using GZIP.  Basically, I'm implementing GZIP using Deflate.  It's related to a school project, hence the potential strangeness.